# git update pull request

Tags: git, pull-request

Suppose I created a pull request on a new branch, then I need to push some additional updates in the same pull request on the same new remote branch, here are my operations, wondering if correct or any better solutions? Thanks.

```
git checkout -b newFooBranch
git add <name of file changed>
git commit -m 'add some initial changes'
git push origin newFooBranch

// make some changes
git add <name of same file changed>
git commit -m 'add some new changes on the same file'
git push origin newFooBranch
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: Yes, just push the additional commits - GitHub will update the PR.

Comment: you should add "-u" parameter, as follows:
git push origin -u newFooBranch
This way, git will track your current branch to remote branch. Without "-u" it will push without tracking (your current branch would be not "connect" with the remote branch and you'll need to specify which remote branch you want to push next time)

Comment: @Klaus, thanks and vote up, you mean add `-u` to which `push` in my above commands? I have two `push` commands.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, thanks and vote up, what do you mean -- "just push the additional commits", could you show me an example?

Comment: Literally exactly what you have already. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, vote up. You mean my current method is fine? I ask here since I am wondering if better/simpler solutions to update changes to an existing pull request. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa, you can put "-u" in either of your commit commands.
That parameter set your local newFooBranch branch to be tracked to newFooBranch on the remote server. You only need to push with "-u" once.

Comment: Thanks @Klaus, vote up. If you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit future people.

Comment: @LinMa, thank you for your vote up, I've added a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LinMa, You could add "-u" parameter to either of your commit commands, the command will become:

```
git push origin -u newFooBranch
```

The "-u" parameter tells git to track (connect) your current local "newFooBranch" to the "newFooBranch" on the remote server. You only need to push with "-u" once for every newly created branch.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Klaus, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the changes are related to the previous change, I would recommend rather using:

```
git add <some changes related to previous commit>
git commit --amend
```

This will just append the changes to the previous commit, that way you don't litter your branch with changesets that mean little on their own.

If you have already pushed commits that could have be rolled into one commit, use `rebase` to either `squash` or `fix` your commits.

Comment: @LinMa No problem :)